# viewpage contain fragment ,the fragment contain a inner viewPage, i found viewPage can`t skip when the fragment hide and inner viewpage don`t move

Tags: android, fragment, viewpage

viewpage contain fragment ,the fragment contain a inner viewPage, i found viewPage can`t skip when  the fragment hide and inner viewpage don`t move the lastest page.The out viewPage event has been Intercepted . how can i solve it 。

Comment: I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

viewpage contain fragment ,the fragment contain a inner viewPage, i found viewPage cant slip when  the fragment hide and inner viewpage dont move the lastest page.The out viewPage event has been Intercepted . how can i solve it 。  sorry !